# Paypal Return url is truncated

Tags: php, paypal, sugarcrm, express-checkout, returnurl

Paypal return url truncates the Query String.

My Paypal return url is :

```
$returnURL = "http://localhost/eko/index.php?module=UserPlans&action=PaymentSuccess&Response=success";
```

and it is truncated after paypal adds up token and payer id.

truncated url becomes

```
http://localhost/eko/index.php?module=UserPlans&token=EC-2F968245J76799249&PayerID=PYEYM7DB7XSNN
```

Truncating the action and response.

My application is based on sugarCrm, module and action in query string is required.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding?

Comment: THANKS PJM It took me nearly 6 hrs to rectify this.

Answer (score 1):

Use URL Encoding

```
$returnURL = urlencode("http://localhost/paypal-test/index.php?module=UserPlans&action=PaymentSuccess&Response=success");
```